# Calculate cumulative percentage by Month and Business Unit in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

hopefully the illustration below sort of paints the picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm wanting to have Excel calculate the % of plan (Column K) distribution for each day (Column J) in a given month (Column H) by business unit (Column E). So essentially, it would look something like this.

- 01/01/2022 - 3.56%
- 01/02/2022 - 2.02%
- 01/03/2022 - 1.98%
- all the way down to 12/31/2022 but each month summed up would total 100%

[image]

Thinking something along the lines of SUMPRODUCT but unsure of how to set it up.